# TopAnchor 0 shows in the middle

Tags: swift, xcode

I have got the `LBTAComponents` framework installed in my Xcode project. Now I want to place my button on the top of the page and the following is my code:

```
button.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)`.
```

The saddening problem with this code is it shows my glorious button in the middle of page rather than on the summit. How can I make my button appear on the top of my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think a moment what you've done: you've pinned all 4 sides of the button (left, right, top and bottom) to the view 4 sides - how can you expect button to be on the top as you want then?

You should use `nil` in **bottom** parameter and set button height in last parameter - **heightConstant**

Answer (score 0):

[SwiftStudier's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41922695/5327882) should work, but you don't need to set the height for the last parameter if you don't need a specific for the button:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = .red
view.addSubview(button)
button.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

Result:

[image]